# Why does compiling with <iostream> cause a 500 error on Apache?

Tags: c++, cgi

I'm experimenting with cgi programming in C++ using gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) and I've encountered a strange error when I try to run it on my commercial apache server.

Apache will run this once it's compiled:

```
#include <cstdio>
// no <iostream>
int main(int c, char **argv)
{
    printf("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n\n");
    printf("Hello printf\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, the server gives back a 500 error if **iostream** gets included

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream> //this will cause a 500 error
int main(int c, char **argv)
{
    printf("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n\n");
    printf("Hello printf\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile that second program with iostream, the program will run perfectly from the command line, but if I upload the code, apache starts kicking back 500 Errors.

Just for the sake of completeness, I compiled similar programs in both C and Free Pascal as well as C++ using just cstdio. No problems...

The problem only arises when I include iostream.

*Note: I didn't forget to change the permissions.*

*Note: I included "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n\n"*

It's like my server just won't accept something compiled with iostream.

Why might **iostream** cause this error when **cstdio** does not and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have the same C++ compiler version on your local computer as on the web server?  I'm going to guess it's not finding the right C++ library on the server.  Perhaps experiment with static linking (ie. add `-static` to the g++ command line) and see if that fixes things in the short run.  If so, then you can move on to checking library versions, using tools such as `ldd`.

Comment: Joe, that was it. Thank you! Would you put that into an answer so I can choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run into this problem when the C++ compiler version on the local machine does not match the version on the server.  In all likelihood, `#include <iostream>` triggers the compiler to bring in code from `libc++`, while leaving it out also leaves out the `libc++` dependency.

To avoid this problem, you can try static linking with `-static`.  This has the advantage of pulling in all the relevant code from your local copy, but does result in a much larger executable and somewhat larger memory footprint.

Alternately, you can investigate the required shared library versions using the tool `ldd`, and ensure appropriate versions get installed on the server machine.